# Installing SQL Server Management Studio on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

FYI, I have BOTH Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate version AND express edition(Visual web developer) installed on my computer.

I open up Web Platform Installer and select "SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Express" and when I try to install a pop-up message appear: "You must install Visual C++ 2008 SP1 before you can install SQL server 2008 Management studio express."

What should I do?

Comment: Install Visual C++ 2008 SP1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install SP1 for Visual Studio before you can install the SQL Server tools.